# Yield of a fission weapon and number of generations to complete

Tags: nuclear-physics

According to [The Nuclear Weapons Archive](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/) it takes about 82 generations for a 20kt device to complete the fission process. This takes just under 600 nanoseconds. What is the relationship between the yield of a nuclear device and the number of generations it takes for the fission process to complete before the core becomes scattered enough that the fission process ceases?

Comment: Your link is a dead end: 404 Error File Not Found

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, my apologies. I used the link directly to the sub-page that describes the nuclear explosion process, which I guess the site doesn't like.

Comment: could you please indicate approximately how to navigate to  the appropriate section of the website?

Comment: Scroll down past the international flags to the FAQ (the site calls it NWFAQ) and select section 2.0, then down to 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but every fission produces about $180$MeV, so after $N$ generations one gets
$$
E\approx 180\times 2^{N}\times (1.602\times 10^{-13})/(4.184\times 10^{12})\hbox{kTons}
$$
equivalent.  The first factor $1.602\times 10^{-13}$ converts MeVs to Joules, and the second factor $4.184\times 10^{12}$ converts Joules to kTon equivalent.  Plugging numbers for $N=82$ yields $33$kTons, which is about right.

The number of generations is practically a little less than $82$; using $81.7$ gives $27$kTons.  The equation is quite sensitive to the number of generation since the yield grows exponentially with $N$, but seems to give a reasonable "order of magnitude" estimate.

As you alluded to, a major hurdle to increasing yield is to physically keep the device in one piece (it is an explosion after all!)

In addition to the excellent site your linked to (which gives a slightly more sophisticated calculus-based expression for the yield), there is a "canonical" text by Friedwardt Winterberg called *The Physical Principles of Thermonuclear Devices* that can be found on the web.  This latter book focuses on fusion devices but there is some "elementary" introduction to fission devices as they serve as triggers for the fusion cycle.

Comment: So basically, this looks like the higher the yield, the longer the time scale, and not the reverse?

Comment: Yes this is what I understand.

Comment: @BillOertell Thanks for this link you provided as it is quite an excellent resource on this type of material.